# Add pagination to dynamically created html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am trying to add pagination to a dynamically generated html . I have added these scripts in my Default.aspx page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type=" text/css" href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<div id = resultDiv></div>
```

The table will appear in this div. 
The table is being created dynamically after obtaining a JSON response from a web service

My **JS** file looks like this

```
 $.ajax({
           url: 'cannot mention',
           method: 'get',
           data: requestData,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {
               var ordersArray = data.orders;
               var i;
               var k;
               var quantityArray;

               var out = "<legend class='bluefont'><b><span id='info'>FOD</span></b></legend>"
               out += "<table id ='tableresult' border='2px' style='font-size: 8pt '>";

               out += "<tr><th> Order Date</th>";

               for (i = 0; i < ordersArray.length; i++) {
                   out += "<td>" + ordersArray[i].orderDate + "</td>";
               }
               out += "</tr>";
               out += "<tr><th>Delivery Date</th>";

               for (i = 0; i < ordersArray.length; i++) {
                   out += "<td>" + ordersArray[i].deliveryDate + "</td>";
               }
               out += "</tr>";
               out += "<tr><th>Quantity</th>";

               for (i = 0; i < ordersArray.length; i++) {
                   quantityArray = ordersArray[i].order

                   for (k = 0; k < quantityArray.length ; k++){
                   out += "<td>" + quantityArray[k].quantity + "</td>";
                   }
               }
               out += "</tr>";
               out += "</table>";

               document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = out;
               document.getElementById("tableresult").dataTable
```

It says dataTable is not a function. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You need to jQuery object to initialize jQuery DataTables. For example:

```
$('#tableresult').DataTable();
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your answer. I did that but it says Data table is not a function

Comment: @CSD, sorry, there was a typo, should be DataTable()

Comment: So should there be a space between Data and Table ? i still get that exception .. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Comment: @CSD, there should not be a space, see [basic example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). Please make sure that jQuery and jQuery DataTables JS/CSS files that are mentined in your question are actually being loaded on that page.